# Is SQLite built into iOS?

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite

I have created a application which uses Sqlite database.

Now i wanted to deploy the application on iPhone and iPad.

I wanted to know whether the Sqlite is inbuilt or not in iPhone/iPad device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, iOS [includes](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html) the SQLite library.

> **SQLite**
>
> iOS includes the popular SQLite
> library, a lightweight yet powerful
> relational database engine that is
> easily embedded into an application.
> Used in countless applications across
> many platforms, SQLite is considered a
> de facto industry standard for
> lightweight embedded SQL database
> programming. Unlike the
> object-oriented Core Data framework,
> SQLite uses a procedural, SQL-focused
> API to manipulate the data tables
> directly.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is inbuilt in iOS. The database is a simple .db(usually)/.sqlite file which you will have to copy as a part of deployment.